Codemirror x86 assembly (Intel) syntax
I'm building an assembly emulator with the x86 syntax. I noticed there is an option for AT&T assembly here.
Is there any know options to support the x86 intel assembly syntax?

What have you found in the docs? Are you sure you're in the right place?

I only found this. So it seems there is no official support

There is only support for AT&T syntax. I found this as well:
https://github.com/r3qip3r/Codemirror_Intel-asm.js
